# a fully backtracking star operator in parsec

Tags: regex, haskell, parsec

I am trying to build a real, fully backtracking + combinator on parsec.

That is, one that receives a parser, and tries to find one or more instances of the given combinator.

That would mean that `parse_one_or_more foolish_a` would be able to match nine chars a in a row, for example. (see code below for context)

As far as I understand it, the reason why it does not currently do so is that, after `foolish_a` finds a match (the first 2 as) the `many1 (try p1)` never gives up on that match.

Is this possible in parsec? Pretty sure it would be very slow (this simple example is already exponential!) but I wonder if it can be done. It is for a programming challenge that runs without time limit -- I would not want to use it in the wild

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)

parse_one_or_more :: Parser String -> Parser String
parse_one_or_more p1 = (many1 (try p1)) >> eof >> return "bababa"

foolish_a = parse_one_or_more (try (string "aa") <|> string "aaa")

good_a = parse_one_or_more (string "aaa")

-- |
-- >>> parse foolish_a "unused triplet" "aaaaaaaaa"
-- Left...
-- ...
-- >>> parse good_a "unused" "aaaaaaaaa"
-- Right...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - Parsec-like libraries can't do this in a way that works for any input. Parsec's implementation of `(<|>)` is left-biased and commits to the left parser if it matches, regardless of anything that may happen later in the grammar. When the two arguments of `(<|>)` overlap, such as in `(try (string "aa") <|> string "aaa")`, there is no way to cause parsec to backtrack into there and try the right side match if the left side succeeded.

If you want to do this, you will need a different library, one that doesn't have a `(<|>)` operator that's left-biased and commits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Parsec produces a recursive-descent parser, you would rather want to make an unambiguous guess first to minimize the need for backtracking. So if your first guess is `"aa"` and that happens to overlap with a later guess `"aaa"`, backtracking is necessary. Sometimes a grammar is *LL(k)* for some *k > 1* and you want to use backtracking out of pure necessity.

The only time I use `try` is when I know that the backtracking is quite limited (*k* is low). For example, I might have an operator `?` that overlaps with another operator `?//`; I want to parse `?` first because of precedence rules, but I want the parser to fail in case it's followed by `//` so that it can eventually reach the correct parse. Here *k = 2*, so the impact is quite low, but also I don't need an operator here that lets me backtrack arbitrarily.

If you want a parser combinator library that lets you fully backtrack all the time, this may come at a severe cost to performance. You could look into [`Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html)'s `+++` symmetric choice operator that picks both. This is an example of what Carl suggested, a `<|>` that is not left-biased and commits.